# AEM 6.5.3 - Issue with WCM IO - Label id is shown instead of Label value on Context aware configurations page

Tags: aem

We have installed the wcm.io package in our AEM instance via inclusion in pom.xml. CA configuration is working fine, except that labels are not shown properly. Instead of a label, it’s showing a label id. I have verified all wcm.io bundles are active in the system/console. I have attached the screenshots below. Any pointers will be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

[image]